# Trying to understand and optimize a mysql query

Tags: mysql

We have a query below. It is working fine where it search for the latest training based on its date. I want to understand why do we put B1.driverTrainingDate< B2.driverTrainingDate and not the other way around and also B2.driverID IS NULL. Is there any other option to improve this query?

```
SELECT driver.driverID,b.driverTrainingDate
 FROM   driver
             LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT B1.*
                      FROM   dTraining AS B1
                             LEFT JOIN  dTraining AS B2
                                    ON B1.driverID = B2.driverID
                                       AND B1.cTrainingID = B2.cTrainingID 
                                       AND B1.driverTrainingDate< B2.driverTrainingDate
                      WHERE B1.cID=".$cTID." And B2.driverID IS NULL) as b
ON ( driver.driverID= b.driverID)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with the `EXPLAIN SELECT` result

Comment: How would you want to write `B1.driverTrainingDate< B2.driverTrainingDate` "the other way around" yet still get the same result?

Comment: @fvu what I need to get the latest training date based on the list of training for a particular driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is intending to return the training date that is just before the complete record but has the null driver id.

'the other way around' would mean the one after... if that data pattern even existed.

Comment: what I need to get the latest training date based on the list of training for a particular driver

Comment: then that should be your question above... maybe open a new question, state your table structure, show some data, then show your desired output.

Comment: ok but based on the above query what can be done or change to optimize it ? Any idea?